# DB System for Crawler Application

Tags: database, web-crawler

I am working on a java based crawler. I want to have the resume functionality in my crawler where user can pause the crawl at any moment he wants and in case something crawler crashed he should be able to start the previous crawl from the point where crawler stopped.

For this purpose I have to store all outlink (link found at any page) in database. I am not sure which database is best for such kind of system as it needs very fast insertion and retrival of links from database and frequency of insertion and retrival would be very high.

Few people suggested me no-sql like mongodb but I just want to make sure that its  the best choice for such kind systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[crawler4j](http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/) is a java crawler that also supports resume functionality. So, if you just want to have a crawler, I suggest to use it. But if you need to integrate this functionality in your own crawler, I suggest Berkeley DB. It is a very efficient key-value based storage. You can check crawler4j's source codes to see how it uses Berkeley DB for very fast storage and retrieval of URLs which need to be crawled.